# Importing scala objects

Tags: scala

I have two different files:
mixer.scala and generate.scala. 
mixer.scala has:

```
package questions
object mixer {bla bla}
```

When try

```
import questions.mixer
```

in my the other file I get "error: object mixer is not a member of package questions"

Comment: Maybe because the object name you have declared is mixter and not mixer

Comment: No, that was a typo here (I double checked :D)

Comment: You get that when compiling the project?

Comment: Yes, I was using ide.c9.io to run it.  I copied the same thing in inteliJ and now it works